# Communication between stackpane scenes JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on my JavaFx project and  I have huge issue. I want my two controllers to communicate with each other. I have read almost all solutions for this problem but I can not find the one for me. I'm beginner programmer and I used some ready-made solutions, which I don't fully understand, for my project and I'm stuck now. My work is so advanced I can not allow to rework it.

Here is my code:

```
public class Main extends Application {
        public static final String ROOT = "Root";
        public static final String ROOT_FXML = "Root.fxml";
        public static final String FIRST_SCREEN = "FirstScreen";
        public static final String FIRST_SCREEN_FXML = "FirstScreen.fxml";
        public static final String SECOND_SCREEN = "SecondScreen";
        public static final String SECOND_SCREEN_FXML = "SecondScreen.fxml";

    @Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    ScreensController mainContainer = new ScreensController();
    initRootLayout();

    mainContainer.loadScreen(Main.FIRST_SCREEN, Main.FIRST_SCREEN_FXML);
    mainContainer.loadScreen(Main.SECOND_SCREEN, Main.SECOND_SCREEN_FXML);
    mainContainer.setScreen(Main.FIRST_SCREEN);


    Group root = new Group();
    root.getChildren().addAll(mainContainer);
    rootLayout.setCenter(root);
}

public void initRootLayout() {
    try {
        // Load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/Root.fxml"));
        rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Interface class

```
public interface ControlledScreen {

    public void setScreenParent(ScreensController screenPage);
}
```

Screens controller class

```
public class ScreensController extends StackPane {

    private HashMap<String, Node> screens = new HashMap<>();

    public void addScreen(String name, Node screen) {
        screens.put(name, screen);
        System.out.println("added screen " + name);
    }

    public boolean loadScreen(String name, String resource) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader myLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(resource));
            Parent loadScreen = (Parent) myLoader.load();
            ControlledScreen myScreenControler = ((ControlledScreen) myLoader.getController());
            myScreenControler.setScreenParent(this);
            addScreen(name, loadScreen);
            return true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean setScreen(final String name) {

        if (screens.get(name) != null) {
            if (!getChildren().isEmpty()) {
                getChildren().remove(0);
                // add new screen
                getChildren().add(0, screens.get(name));
            } else {
                getChildren().add(screens.get(name));
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("screen hasn't been loaded!\n");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean unloadScreen(String name) {
        if (screens.remove(name) == null) {
            System.out.println("Screen didn't exist");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment I have two controller classes with two different fxml files. They look like this:

```
public class FirstScreenController implements ControlledScreen {

    ScreensController myController;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {

    }

    @Override
    public void setScreenParent(ScreensController screenPage) {
        myController = screenPage;

    }
}
```

Is there a simple way to communicate between first and second screen ?

Comment: Since both your controllers have references to the same `ScreensController` instance, why not just put some JavaFX properties in that class. Then you can modify and observe the same property from both controllers. (In general, though, "I copied some code from the internet that I don't understand" is not really a good starting point for anything. You need to understand how the code you are using works. If you don't, you won't get very far, and posting here won't really help: no-one else can understand it for you.)

Comment: Well I know that. I just can not figgure out how to pass values from first screen to the second.

Comment: But if you did that, why would you need to pass values from one controller to the other?